# The strange SMS

Tags: cipher

I was talking with a friend via SMS when suddently, he sent me a strange message :

```
(16)(39)(26)(36)(25)(34)(12)(34)(47)(36)(28)(18)(36)(33)(22)(12)(18)(18)(23)(37)(39)
```

I asked what was going on but he didn't answer me ...
Can someone help me, what did he tell me ?

### Hints

Hint 1 :

> Tags can help you

Hint 2 :

> Context is like size ... it matters.

Hint 3 :

> This is a joke, there are only 2 hints.

Comment: I edited the question to correct the sentence

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you interpret each two-digit number as

> The second number repeated the first number of times, so that (39) becomes 999,

We can interpret the full string as:

> 6-999-66-666-55-444-2-444-7777-666-88-8-666-333-999-777-33-8-8-1-1

Which looks a lot like

> Texting on an old phone keyboard.

Interpreting the numbers in this way gives us the string

> MYNOKIAISOUTOFYRETT.,

Which, with spaces, says

> My Nokia is out of yrett.,
>
>  I expect this last word is 'battery' backwards, since ".," would be AB if it were on the second key, and not the first. I have yet to determine why that last word is backwards in the first place.

Comment: Was it really THAT easy ?

Comment: @therandomguy, tell us why that last word is backwards!