# The strange SMS (Part 2)

Tags: cipher

Thanks to all of you, I know now what my friend was telling me (see [part one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/18601/13384)).
We continued talking via Skype. After some nice messages about the utility of iron in our society, we decided to meet in 15 minutes.
I arrived early, as usual.

I waited 20 minutes, then I received a strange SMS (he recharged his Nokia) :

```
(255) (153) (153) (255) (231) (129) (129) (153) (255)
```

When I asked him what was going on, he didn't answer me.

### Question

What did he send me?
Why is he late?
Where were we planning to meet?

### Hints

Hint 1 :

> Tags can help you.

Hint 2 :

> Context is like size... it matters.

Hint 3 :

> Stop looking for another hint! Do you think this is a game?

Comment: so clearly we start with 25 5's...

Comment: @Goinghamateur or possibly 55 2's, if he's trying to trick us this time...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What did he send me?

Well, as found by Aioros,

> Translating the numbers into binary returns what appears to be a "creeper" from the game Minecraft:
>
> ```
> 11111111
> 10011001
> 10011001
> 11111111
> 11100111
> 10000001
> 10000001
> 10011001
> 11111111
> ```

Next,

> Why is he late?

Well, given the situation, he was probably

> Blasted to smithereens.

And finally,

> Where were we planning to meet?

Again, given the situation,

> The discussion about the utility of iron could be hinting at the Iron Golems in the game that can protect villages. Because of this, I would guess that you and your friend are villagers, and you were planning to meet at the village.

Comment: Gongratulation, you figured what happened :) PS: if you want multiple lines in a spoiler tag use <br> to add a new line

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I haven't played the game in two years, but that face never leaves you.

Comment: Having looked up the answer, with which i was unfamiliar, i'm afraid that (a) line 4 should not exist and (b) lines 6,7,8 (or, then, 5,6,7) should all be 66 higher than they are.

Comment: http://www.google.ca/imgres?imgurl=https://www.jinx.com/content/prod/3315p_28c_4b.jpg&imgrefurl=https://www.jinx.com/p/minecraft_creeper_plush_toy_with_sound.html&h=800&w=600&tbnid=7EJqaFMFfwqrJM:&docid=z4-xjVAYtc2a1M&ei=7uXCVY3NF5GuyASz-qnQAQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CFkQMygeMB5qFQoTCI384sfSk8cCFREXkgodM30KGg

Answer (score 8):

I'll go with a partial answer to get this started: the given numbers

> have an interesting property when translated to binary. They look like this:
>
>
>  `11111111`
>
>  `10011001`
>
>  `10011001`
>
>  `11111111`
>
>  `11100111`
>
>  `10000001`
>
>  `10000001`
>
>  `10011001`
>
>  `11111111`

I guess this should tell me something, but I haven't figured out what yet.

Comment: Unfocusing my eyes a little, it looks like an 'I' and an 'A'?

Comment: Well, maybe, but that doesn't mean a lot. I was trying to find something in a similar fashion, though.

Comment: I hate to suggest it, but the classic Creepers from Minecraft?

Comment: It looks like a [creeper face](http://www.imagenesdeminecraft.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/minecraft-creeper-face-yahylaqv.png) from the game minecraft.

Comment: Well, it certainly looks like it. Only problem is, I don't have the faintest idea what that is.

Comment: You did it ! But you didn't find what happened ..

Comment: (I got the binary, and saw the unhappy face, but had no idea what it was from.)

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Following on from the solution to the first SMS puzzle, and so trying to work out how often to press a number key to generate a certain letter:

> 55 is the decimal code for the ASCII character '7', and 53 is the code for '5'. Using a phone keypad again, 255 -> 2 **7**s -> **R**, and 153 -> 1 **5** -> **J**

That only covers two potential letters, though.