# The strange SMS (Part 3)

Tags: cipher

It is very hard to communicate with my friend, as you can see [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/18657/13384) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/18601/13384) ...
The next day I was finally able to talk to him, so we decided to meet in a real place ([the last one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/18601/13384) wasn't safe enough). To avoid his messages I called him. I wanted to meet at the park, near the cinema. He wasn't really motivated. When I asked him what was wrong, he suddenly hung up his phone. 
He then sent me a strange SMS (again!):

```
(13384) (001)(101)(511)(990)
```

I asked what was going on but as always, he didn't answer...

### Question

What is he trying to tell me ?

### Hints

Hint 1:

> Tags can help you.

Hint 2:

> Context is like size ... it **doesn't** mater. (Maybe a little bit.)

Hint 3:

> The space between the first and the other numbers **is** relevant. They are 2 different things.

Hint 4:

> Focus on the second part of the numbers

Hint 5:

> Stop waiting for an other hint here ... If I could, I would go back and delete all of my hints, and go in the park of the ward.

Comment: This seems to be harder than the other ones. Just a question, is the space between the first and the second number relevant?

Comment: Just to save people the effort, but not really worth an answer itself, hint 4 reads: "focus on the second part of the numbers" with a Caesar shift of 1.

Comment: I think this wasn't very interessing, so i deleted the cryptogram on hint 4 and i added directly the tip

Comment: Is the message on your profile a hint towards this puzzle?

Comment: this isn't a hint ... but it's a part of the puzzle ._.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What i figured out so far:

The (13384) refer to:

> Your Profile: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/13384/the-random-guy

We get a new Text:

> i am your frIend, dear tHe rAndom guy ! i can'T communicatE with You because my nOkia is oUt of battery aGain ! i wanted tO warn you via your adress mail buT i cOuldn't figure wHat is your mail ... so the only way i found is to writE you a message here. i wont be abLe to taLk to you for now, i am sorry :/

With a Little hidden Message:

> Only The Upper Case Letters:  HATE YOU GO TO HELL

i couldn't figure out what the next Numbers mean, but i think he

> just dont like you :)

**Edit**

I got a really far fetched answer for the secound Numbers..

Okay first of all:

> We turn them around: 100 101 115 099

Decode with ASCII:

> desc

And that leads to:

> your **desc**ription in your Profile :)

Comment: You solved the puzzle ! I will accept your answer when you will solve the second pArt of the numberS. This Comment hIde a hInt !

Comment: I coulnd't come up with something better... xD

Comment: @The random guy I Did not expect that to be right :)