# My friend's bounty

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

### Story

I love doing stuff with my friends on Buzzing Shark Exchange. This time my friend finally decided to create an account on this site.
We wanted to have fun, so I created a cryptogram:

> What is this sequence of numbers about?
>   $953562951413$

I promised to give a bounty of 50 reputation to the one who found the answer. I gave this to my friend before I posted it, so he would be able to find the solution and have the bounty. He got ninja'd, and he lost the opportunity to answer correctly.
Next day, this friend sent me an SMS (a [normal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18601/the-strange-sms) one):

```
Hey buddy, i posted an enigm on the site. If you answer it correctly i'll give you a bounty.
```

I searched his post on the site. His only activity was a question posted yesterday:

> I have a list of letters... what comes next?
>   `O S A J J M ???`

Easy, huh?
I luckily answered it first and, as he promised, he gave me a bounty. However, my reputation didn't go up!

### Question

- Why didn't my reputation go up?
- **Bonus**: What are the answers to the numbers and the letter sequence?

### Clarifications

- Buzzing Shark Exchange works exactly as Puzzling Stack Exchange. The only difference is that it is allowed for sharks.
- This site works correctly. There are no bugs (sharks know how to code!)

Comment: I cleaned up the grammar/punctuation a bit. If I ruined the puzzle, feel free to roll it back. :) I didn't touch anything in the SMS message, since I didn't know if it was important or not - is 'enigm' purposeful?

Comment: Who says the bounty is a bounty on Shark Exchange? It could be a chocolate bar he gave you ;)

Comment: Thank you @BaileyM, I definely have a problem with english D:

Comment: No problem at all. It's certainly good enough to make a solid puzzle! I just cleaned up a few spots. There have been posts on here that I skipped completely because they were just unreadable (and yours are not among them)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the main question:

> If his only activity was a single question, your friend did not have the reputation to offer a bounty. I can only assume he gave you a [coconut-filled chocolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounty_(chocolate_bar)) instead. Or perhaps there are numerous people closing in on you, even now, attempting to take you, alive or dead, to your (presumably former) friend
> EDIT: If you were given a bounty, you would have been told about someone else to go capture and bring to the authorities/the bounty giver. I got my old west knowledge backwards, sorry.

Comment: (+1) Now I also know why TheRandomGuy didn't answer my unserious comment :D

Comment: @LuxxMiner unserious but valid .. You got it, gg ! EDIT : i will valid this answer tomorrow, i wanna see some other lateral thinking answer :D

Comment: Sorry, @LuxxMiner! I didn't see your comment before I posted, or I would have suggested you post it as an answer!

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat No problem! I'm just a bit *angry at myself* and at noone else, no need for an apology, I'm sure you wouldn't have exploit my comment for your own answer!

Answer (score 7):

> The sequence of numbers is the first 12 digits of pi (π) in reverse. (The last digit (or first digit in the sequence) is rounded off, thanks Vašek Potoček.)

There's another bonus question cracked!

Comment: Not quite, is it? Isn't there an extra 5 floating around in there? **EDIT:** Never mind, he fixed it. :D

Comment: Yes you are right, i corrected that. +1 for this bonus answer !

Comment: That, and the last (or first) digit 9 is wrong, unless that's a decimal approximation of π rounded at that point.

Comment: @VašekPotoček this is rounded :D

Comment: I think it would be harder if the digits were separated by commas.

Comment: @Anachor this small sequence wasn't suppose to be hard, that was just a small bonus question :D

Answer (score 5):

> The letter sequence is first letter of the months starting from October going backwards. So the next letter in the sequence should be A for April.

That's one bonus question out of the way.

Answer (score 4):

Well since you and your friend are clearly sharks, the bounty he gave you might have been the

> H.M.S. Bounty, full of tasty tasty sailors.

Alas, such a bounty will not award you reputation.

Comment: cannibalism !! D:

Comment: No, because the sailors aren't sharks.

Comment: @Kingrames are you sure about that?

Comment: @FarazMasroor well, not site reputation, I'm sure. Being the shark that ate up a famous ship would make you quite infamous, however.

Comment: @Kingrames I was wondering about sailor sharks. I'm pretty sure there are such things

Comment: I couldn't find anything. you might be thinking of something close.

Answer (score 3):

> If you have been busy on Buzzing Shark Exchange you may have already hit the daily +200 rep limit, so it cannot increase any further.

Comment: Interessing answer, i didn't know you are limited on reputation every day ... EDIT : what about 250 rep bounties ?

Comment: Bounties are exempt from the daily rep cap